# Getting facebook USER TOKEN inside java desktop app

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

I have developed a java application which post data updates on the facebook user wall, i'm using facebook4j api (http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html) i´ve tested and it works great, but the problem is that i generate manually the user token (from Facebook dev tool) , and i need something that automatically give me an access token. Im getting no idea how to do it, maybe a login form inside my app and ask facebook for the token giving username and login. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

> i generate manually the user token (from Facebook dev tool)

This is the wrong way to get the access token. You can get the access token once the user [logged-in](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate/) to/authenticate your app. Just like this-

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session.isOpened()) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), session.getAccessToken(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```